# Use Attribute to create Request IP constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to do the following (Pseudo Code):

```
[InternalOnly]
public ActionResult InternalMethod()
{ //magic }
```

The "`InternalOnly`" attribute is for methods that should check the `HttpContext` request IP for a known value before doing anything else.

How would I go about creating this "`InternalOnly`" attribute?

Comment: A similar post has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a custom filter attribute:

```
public class InternalOnly : FilterAttribute
{
    public void OnAuthorization (AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsIntranet (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            throw new HttpException ((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Access forbidden.");
        }
    }

    private bool IsIntranet (string userIP)
    {
        // match an internal IP (ex: 127.0.0.1)
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty (userIP) && Regex.IsMatch (userIP, "^127");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.. I've written my code exactly as you have, but the attribute doesn't fire/has no effect.... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a problem that can be solved with an AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming) solution.  For this type of thing I usually recommend [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).

Basically what PostSharp allows you to do is create attributes that you can use as markers for places in your code that you wish to insert boilerplate code.