# restrict access to mvc controller using ip address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm following solution
 [which is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta)

my controller in mvc3 is decorated with custom FilterIP attribute like this

```
 //Admin/Device/Edit/1
    [FilterIP(
            ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs = "AllowedAdminSingleIPs",
            ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs = "AllowedAdminMaskedIPs",
            ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs = "DeniedAdminSingleIPs",
            ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs = "DeniedAdminMaskedIPs"
    )]
    public ActionResult Edit(int Id).... ommiting
```

and in Web.config I'm having these values inside appSettings

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="AllowedAdminSingleIPs" value="89.111.212.141"/>
  <add key="AllowedAdminMaskedIPs" value="10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0"/>
  <add key="DeniedAdminSingleIPs" value=""/>
  <add key="DeniedAdminMaskedIPs" value=""/>
 </appSettings>
```

Now, I'm using http://www.whatismyip.com/
to discover my current ip (cause I'm having dynamic ip from isp). 
As far as I know this should work after I use my ip inside 
  .
89.111.212.141 is my isp dynamic ip. But it doesnt work.

What can be a problem ?
I'm constantly redirected to login when reacing decorated controller action.
Just to mention, when using localhost as a AllowedAdminSingleIPs it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have hosted your application locally (VS built-in web server) and accessing it locally chances are your IP is 127.0.0.1 as returned by `httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress`. Try debugging the code by placing breakpoints in order to see what's going on.

Comment: I am hosting locally inside vs and trying to access my controller locally inside debug mode. When I change key value from localhost to 127.0.0.1 access do not work again. Basically only when using localhost as a value it's working. Is this means that It should be fine when my app be hosted online ?

Comment: @hi, darin, allow the certain  IP addresses access  mvc pages that would otherwise be inaccessible to the public, how that can be done ? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29368702/2218697) is my problem for facebook share, will [this](http://www.sasanyeganegi.com/2013/12/how-to-restrict-access-by-ip-in-aspnet.html) work or should i ask a new question ?