# facebook share on page you manage in asp.net mvc

Tags: facebook

i am trying to share product details in facebook from our website in asp mvc, i used feed dialog   and it works fine, but i need and additional options in feed dialog  to share on page you manage

**feed dialog**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1234567891000&link=http://www.example.com/Product/@product.ProductID&name=@product.Title&caption=Get%20More%20this%20month,%20only%20at%20example.com&description=@product.description&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/&picture=http://www.example.com/pics/@(product.ProductID).jpg" target="_blank"><div style="width:60px;float:left;"><img style="text-align:center" src="@Url.Content("~/image/fbshare.jpg")" alt="fbshare" /></div></a>
```

didn't work, so i tried **sharer.php**

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://www.example.com/Product/@product.ProductID&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.example.com/pics/@(product.ProductID).jpg&amp;p[title]=@product.Title+&amp;p[summary]=@product.description"><div style="width:60px;float:left;"><img style="text-align:center" src="@Url.Content("~/image/fbshare.jpg")" alt="fbshare" /></div></a>
```

but when i share using sharer.php it shares my site login Page, our product site is login based, users can view all products , but when they click buy , they have to login to proceed further.

i dont know, why does facebook share my login Page instead of product details ?

How can i provide options like share on page you manage, timeline , friends etc ?

[image]

its been hours, i couldn't find any solution still, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook bot visits the shared URL, grabs the page information (headers, images etc) and uses that to decide what to display to the users.

Your site likely is redirecting the Facebook bot to the login page - so it does not actually see anything related to the product.

The usual work around for this is to exclude the login for the Facebook IP range, or for the Facebook user-agents. Typically you should present a simplified page to the Facebook bot.

Check out the Facebook help page regarding how to make sure the Crawler (bot) can access your site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl

Comment: thank you, for pointing out that, so i am planning exclude the login for the Facebook IP range, may be [this](http://www.sasanyeganegi.com/2013/12/how-to-restrict-access-by-ip-in-aspnet.html) is what i suppose to do  , ok do you know any easy method to do that in asp mvc ?

Comment: I don't think thats what you need to use - that would **restrict** access to the Facebook IP range - you need to **allow** it. How are you authenticating users on the site? Consider posting a new question asking how to allow certain IPs with that authentication system and include the code where you verify the users?

Comment: yep what you said is correct, soon i will find a solution to allow access