# ASP.NET MVC - allow access to certain actions from certain domain names only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, subdomain

I have integrated a 3rd party payment processor in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. This payment processor calls my controller action to send me the status of a transaction. I want to ensure that this action can be called only by the given payment processor and not by users themselves.

The first idea is to use UserHostAddress and the solution provided here:
[Restrict access to a specific controller by IP address in ASP.NET MVC Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta)

But the problem is that the payment processor might call me from various IP addresses which are not known to me. The only thing they specify is that the callbacks will come from certain domains (but multiple subdomains). They suggest the following filter: *.paymentproc.com

Thus, the question is as follows:
**How do I limit my controller action to be executable only from IPs which correspond to domain pattern *.paymentproc.com?**

Comment: Can't you use the same method but register dnsnames when you define the attribute on a method, and verify the httpContext.Request.UserHostName (instead of UserHostAddress) value?

Comment: I have read that UserHostName is not reliable or might need additional settings - it is disabled by default because resolving DNS for each request would be too expensive operation. I guess, I'll have to find some function how to get domain name from UserHostAddress only for some certain requests.