# How to make Azure websites "private" during development?

Tags: azure

We want to implement continuous deployment of a web application (front-end and back-end REST API being 2 virtual directories or 2 websites) towards Windows Azure.  How can we keep these websites private and thus make them not available to the large public ?  We do not want that somebody discovers the URL of our development/staging environment and starts "playing" with it.

But we ofcourse want that our development team and test team can access the web applications ...

We are searching for a simple solution ...

thx

Comment: Just to clarify: You're using Azure Web Sites? Not cloud services (web/worker) to host the web site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using Azure Web Sites: Unlike Cloud Services (web & worker roles), you cannot deploy to a staging environment - anyone will be able to find your website (or at least *can attempt* to find it). Having said that: You can now set up Dynamic IP Address Restrictions (DIPR), to block / allow access. This is set up in the `<system.webServer>` element. For example:

```xml
<system.webServer>   
  <security> 
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound"> 
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="10.1.2.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/> 
    </ipSecurity> 
  </security>    
</system.webServer>
```

Note the `allowUnlisted` attribute. Setting it to false will block all IP addresses aside from the ones you specify.

See [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/09/26/windows-azure-new-virtual-machine-active-directory-multi-factor-auth-storage-web-site-and-billing-improvements.aspx) by Scott Guthrie for more details.

**EDIT June 11, 2014 - Staging slots were added to Web Sites in January 2014.** This requires a *Standard* plan. You'll find the option in the dashboard:

[image]

You can then create a separate slot. Here's an example with a guid, for a bit of security-by-obscurity, which is similar to what you have with Cloud Services (web/worker roles):

[image]

Now you'll see your primary deployment slot, along with any additional you created. You can then do deployment swaps as well.

[image]

You'll now see the **Swap** button at the bottom, when viewing the Dashboard tab:

[image]

You then choose which deployment slot to switch with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to mind is to filter out by IP addresses, if that's possible for your team.

[See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta).