# How do I restrict access by IP address to my Asp.Net MVC controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there something like:

```
    [Allow IP 123.123.12]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string xml)
    {

         //Only allow posts from the above IP
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict access to a specific controller by IP address in ASP.NET MVC Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta)

Comment: You should do that in IIS, not MVC. There's no point paying the CPU processing cost for a request that could be rejected before it even entered the pipeline

Comment: Agree @PanagiotisKanavos, unless you don't own the deployment environment (perhaps there is a way to do it in .config).

It would be easy enough to inherit from the Authentication attribute (I can't remember the exact name) and apply your own rules.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - IIS sounds even better, can you provide where this would be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr. Kanavos, yes this is much better handled with IIS and webconfig.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity